munge/slurm authentication issue (Protocol authentication error)
I have a slurm cluster of one grid and 6 compute nodes. 5 nodes are up and 1 node is down. It's slurmd status was talking about munge auth errors, then I restarted and they went away, but then the errors showed up in the slurmctl status. Here is the slurmctl status:
● slurmctld.service - Slurm controller daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slurmctld.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-05-28 12:14:31 CDT; 2min 45s ago
   Main PID: 8086 (slurmctld)
      Tasks: 11
     Memory: 3.5M
        CPU: 88ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/slurmctld.service
             ├─8086 /usr/sbin/slurmctld -D -s
             └─8087 "slurmctld: slurmscriptd"

May 28 12:16:52 redacted.hostname slurmctld[8086]: slurmctld: error: slurm_unpack_received_msg: [[comp04]:port_number] auth_g_verify: MESSAGE_NODE_REG>
May 28 12:16:52 redacted.hostname slurmctld[8086]: slurmctld: error: slurm_unpack_received_msg: [[comp04]:port_number] Protocol authentication error
May 28 12:16:52 redacted.hostname slurmctld[8086]: slurmctld: error: slurm_receive_msg [ip_address_]: Protocol authentication error
May 28 12:17:08 redacted.hostname slurmctld[8086]: slurmctld: error: Munge decode failed: Rewound credential
May 28 12:17:08 redacted.hostname slurmctld[8086]: slurmctld: auth/munge: _print_cred: ENCODED: Tue May 28 12:22:01 2024
May 28 12:17:08 redacted.hostname slurmctld[8086]: slurmctld: auth/munge: _print_cred: DECODED: Tue May 28 12:17:01 2024
May 28 12:17:08 redacted.hostname slurmctld[8086]: slurmctld: error: Check for out of sync clocks
May 28 12:17:08 redacted.hostname slurmctld[8086]: slurmctld: error: slurm_unpack_received_msg: [[comp04]:port_number2] auth_g_verify: MESSAGE_NODE_REG>
May 28 12:17:08 redacted.hostname slurmctld[8086]: slurmctld: error: slurm_unpack_received_msg: [[comp04]:port_number2] Protocol authentication error
May 28 12:17:08 redacted.hostname slurmctld[8086]: slurmctld: error: slurm_receive_msg [ip_address_]: Protocol authentication error

I have not had this issue until I had restart my nodes after a power outage. Prior to this, these nodes have been connected and functional for about a year. I assume I need to resync munge between the grid and the node, but I do not know how. Any suggestions?

First place to look is in the error logs there:
Check for out of sync clocks

Set up chronyd or ntpd and make sure your clocks are in sync across all nodes.

First check ntpd or chronyd and then try to restart munge service then restart slurmd at nodes then restart slurmctl service

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I did as the 2 comments suggested and used the date command to check the times. My fourth node was 5 minutes ahead and its chronyd daemon was deactivated, likely due to the power outage. I restarted the chronyd daemon, restarted the munge daemon, restarted the slurmd daemon, and restarted the slurmctld daemon as the comments suggested. All the statuses of the nodes were active and without errors, but the node was still offline due to an "unexpected boot". I then used sudo scontrol update node=comp02 state=resume to get the nodes back online.

try doing dpkg-reconfigure tzdata on all the nodes.
